# adb backup doesn't work on non-rooted oneplus2

Tags: android, adb, oneplustwo

When I tried to back up my app data, it doesn't work. Specs are listed below:

- oneplus2 ONE A2005
- OxygenOS: 3.5.8
- Android : 6.0.1

The phone is not rooted, Developer Options is on and it's debuggable.

I run

```
./adb backup -noapk com.bla.android -f /blafolder
```

on my linux box. The phone then asks for a password and if I want to backup my data, after I choose backup, it says backup starting and then immediately shows backup finished, and of course there is no backed up file on my linux.

The app data is available because i can run the same command for my other android phone, i.e. a moto Z and get the complete app data.

This happens to other apps as well, in other words, I can copy app data for several other apps on the other phone, but can't on my OP2. I googled and got some other responses, like having the app running in the backgroup while backup, but nothing worked. Can someone please kindly shed some light. Thank you very much.

Best,
Z

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured I actually had a desktop password, that is the problem. After I typed that in, the backup went through without any issue.

I thought I never set up any desktop password ( not the encryption backup password), which caused me lots of unnecessary time and energy. You can change the desktop password in the developer options.